# Error "'name' attribute should be defined" When Trying to List Permissions in AdroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-manifest

I'm new to android studio and after a Gradle update I get an error when hovering over the two `uses-permission` I wrote into the file. The error message is: 'name' attribute should be defined. Here is the code  dealing with the permissions below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.actually_not.atypicalcameraeffectsapp">

    //Permissions
    <uses-permission andriod:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature andriod:name="android.hardware.camera.any" />
    <uses-permission andriod:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-feature andriod:name="android.hardware.microphone" />

    <application
        ...
```

Apparently I'm on Android Gradle Plugin Version 4.0.1 and Gradle Version 6.1.1. I have no idea what the differences between the two are.

Should I try rolling back to a different version of one of the Gradles, is there something wrong with my code, or is it something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the spelling of the `name` tag of each permission. `andriod:name` should be `android:name`. :)

Comment: Wow I had a epic facepalm moment there. Thanks